# Is it possible to extend an existing custom field set to allow multiple values?

Tags: custom-fields

I have a site with a number of custom field sets. I need to change one of those to allow multiple values. Specifically, the field set holds fields relating to a vehicle; the site now needs to allow each contact to have multiple vehicles. The field set in question is assigned only to the Individual contact type.

I can see the option "Does this Custom Field Set allow multiple records?" on the field set settings page, but I can't enable it. However, if I create a new field set, this option is available.

I"m assuming that once created, you can't enable this option on a field set, although I can't find this documented. But I want to be sure before I delete the field set and recreate it with this option enabled.

Thanks for any guidance on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only edit the settings for allowing multiple records if the custom set is an empty set, i.e, the checkbox for this setting is only shown for those custom sets for which the custom table created has no rows in it.

This is [checked here](https://github.com/jitendrapurohit/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Custom/Form/Group.php#L375-L376). variable `$this->_isGroupEmpty` is set to FALSE if you have any record in the custom table.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I thought the answer was, but I wanted to be sure.